# Convert 16-bit signed int to 2-bytes?

Tags: c#

I got an array which contains signed int data, i need to convert each value in the array to 2 bytes. I am using C# and i tried using `BitConverter.GetBytes(int)` but it returns a 4 byte array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A signed 16-bit value is best represented as a `short` rather than `int` - so use [`BitConverter.GetBytes(short)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk3sts66.aspx).

However, as an alternative:

```
byte lowByte = (byte) (value & 0xff);
byte highByte = (byte) ((value >> 8) & 0xff);
```