# Concatenating bytes into integer or short preserving sign

Tags: c#

I know I can extract bytes from int like this:

```
bytes[] IntToBytes(int i)
{
  return new byte [] {(byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xff), (byte) (i & 0xff)};
}
```

which I subsequently send as part of a serial transmission. But can I do the reverse, after receiving a sequence of bytes, reconstruct the original data, preserving the sign. Currently, I do this, but it feels a bit over the top:

```
int BytesToInt( byte hi, byte lo)
{
  return ((hi << 24) | (lo << 16)) >> 16;
}
```

Is there another way or a better way? Does it make a difference if I know I am ultimately dealing with signed 16-bit data only?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538390/convert-16-bit-signed-int-to-2-bytes

Comment: @josh BitConverter looks ideal, subject to passing the endian test.

Comment: `(int)BitConverter.ToInt16(new[] {lo, hi}, 0);`

Comment: @Sinatr This is remote communication - the endianness can be different on the two machines.

Answer (score 2):

You're working with signed 16-bit data only. So why are you passing (and returning) an `int` and not a `short`? You're throwing the sign information away, so it will not actually work for negative numbers. Instead, use `short` and you'll be fine - and the extra type information will make your code safer.

```
byte[] ShortToBytes(short i)
{
  return new byte [] {(byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xff), (byte) (i & 0xff)};
}

short BytesToShort(byte hi, byte lo)
{
  return unchecked((short)((hi << 8) | lo));
}
```

The main benefit (apart from being clearer and actually *working*) is that you can no longer pass an invalid value to the method. That's always good :)

Oh, and I'd recommend keeping the interface symmetric - `BytesToShort` should also take a `byte[]` (or some other structure that has the two bytes).

Comment: This causes overflow with negative numbers

Comment: No it doesn't. I tested it for negative numbers, as well as a random set of numbers. Are you perhaps switching `hi` and `lo`? Another reason to use `byte[]` for both the return value of `ShortToBytes` and `BytesToShort` :)

Comment: Interesting. I get overflow with any call to `BytesToShort` where value of `hi > 127`. Could be a difference with Checked/Unchecked setting

Comment: @Graham Oh, are you testing in LINQPad? It has `checked` arithmetic by default. But I added the explicit `unchecked` statement anyway, it's good practice :)